# Integrating with PandaPay javascript library on Angular 2 requires listening for a Javascript method. How to catch this in an angular method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am adding PandaPay to my application, which is pretty similar to stripe but makes it easier to make donations to charities. Unfortunately, unlike Stripe, they obscure a lot of the services and the only example they give for creating a credit card token is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV4F8.jpg

So instead of being able to make the request myself passing in the cc number, etc. I have to specify the field types exactly as they are in the sample form and import Panda.js. And then catch the success or failure in the javascript Panda.on('success') function.

I can catch this by placing the javascript function in my index.html, but I want to be able to catch this in my registration component ts file as an angular method in order to send the contents of the token to my backend.

Should I keep this Panda.on() method in my index.html? If so, how do I call an angular function from a standard javascript function.

Is there a way to get Panda.on() to trigger an angular method instead? Essentially I don't like this asynchronous call since the credit card tokenization is part of the user registration for my site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you had an answer on another site (I was searching for something similar).

Anyway, for others coming here, I fetched the PandaPay js in `index.html` like normal, and my component looks like this:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var Panda: any;

@Component({
    ....
})
export class DonationSetup implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(...) {  }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        Panda.init('my_key', 'panda_cc_form');
        Panda.on('success', (cardToken) => {
            console.log(cardToken);
            // Do stuff with the token here
        });
        Panda.on('error', (errors) => {
            console.log(errors);
            // Do stuff with errors here
        });
    }
}
```

And your template could look something like this:

```
<form id="panda_cc_form">
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" data-panda="first_name">
    </div>

    <!-- Remaining input fields and submit button -->
</form>
```

I am using Ionic so my declarations are already sorted out, but [here](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/javascript-libraries-in-a-typescript-application-revisited/) is a good resource on importing javascript libraries into Typescript.

## On Ionic...

I ran into a problem with the Panda library discovering the correct input fields. This is because `<ion-input>` is a wrapper which, during runtime, creates a child `<input>` field. The attributes carry over, creating duplicate `data-panda` attributes for both the parent and child elements. To solve this, I did as follows:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var Panda: any;

@Component({
    ....
})
export class DonationSetup implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('fn') fn: any;  // first_name
    @ViewChild('ln') ln: any;  // last_name
    @ViewChild('cc') cc: any;  // credit_card
    @ViewChild('ex') ex: any;  // expiration
    @ViewChild('cv') cv: any;  // cvv

    constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2,
                // Other Ionic stuff) {  }


    ngAfterViewInit() {   
        this._renderer.setAttribute(this.fn._elementRef.nativeElement.children[0], 'data-panda', 'first_name');
        this._renderer.setAttribute(this.ln._elementRef.nativeElement.children[0], 'data-panda', 'last_name');
        // Remaining elements
        // ...
        // ...

        Panda.init('my_key', 'panda_cc_form');
        Panda.on('success', (cardToken) => stuff );
        Panda.on('error', (errors) => stuff);
    }
}
```

and my template looks like:

```
<ion-content>
    <form id="panda_cc_form">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>First Name</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" #fn ></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <!-- remaining input fields and submit button -->
        </ion-list>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

#### Explanation

For each `<ion-input>` field, we have to access the child `<input>` element and set the `data-panda` attribute without also adding the attribute to the parent. To do this, we attach a template reference `#fn` to each of the `<ion-input>` fields (using the appropriate reference for the other fields).

We then access that reference with the `@ViewChild('fn') fn: any;` line.
We use `Renderer2` to set the attribute using its `.setAttribute()` method, giving it the first child in the `children` array for the `el: any` argument, `'data-panda-` for the `name: string` argument, and `'first_name'` for the `value: string` argument. This is done for each `<ion-input>` reference, with the appropriate `data-panda` value for the `value: any` argument.

This solution is sort of code-heavy, and I'm sure there is a more concise way, or altogether different way to do this. If so, please let me know.